# sObject Variable Assignment keeps the same values

Tags: apex, apex-variable

I have a question regarding variable's assignment and the values within them.

```
Account a = new Account(Name = 'TMP');
system.debug(Logginglevel.INFO,  'a '+a); // Name = 'TMP'
Account b = new Account();
b=a;

b.Name = 'TMP NEW';
system.debug(Logginglevel.INFO,  'a '+a); // Name = 'TMP NEW'
```

As you can see I create an `Account` object `tmpVariable` and assigning the `Name = 'TMP'`
Then I create a new `Account` object `tmpVariable` and assigning the first one. For the second one I change the `Name = 'TMP NEW'`. When I debug log the first `tmpVariable` I can see that this is also changed. Why is this happening and how can I overcome it so as the first variable keeps its value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Apex, variables are either primitive types or reference types. [Primitive types store the actual values, while reference types store the references (or pointers) to the objects in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45053461/what-happens-when-you-assign-the-value-of-one-variable-to-another-variable-in-py).
- When you assign one variable to another, you are either copying the value or the reference, depending on the type of the variable. For primitive types, you are copying the value, so changing one variable does not affect the other. For reference types, you are copying the reference, so changing one variable affects the other, because they both point to the same object.
- In your code, [Account is a reference type, because it is a class that represents a Salesforce object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540824/why-does-assigning-value-to-one-variable-update-another-variable). Therefore, when you assign a to b, you are copying the reference to the same Account object in memory. When you change the name of b, you are changing the name of that object, which is also reflected by a. [That is why both variables have the same name after the assignment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970152/why-cant-i-assign-the-value-of-one-variable-to-another)
- To overcome this behavior, you need to create a new Account object and copy the values of the fields from one object to another. [You can use the clone method of the SObject class to do this easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604136/assign-variable-to-another-variable-and-have-changes-in-one-be-mirrored-in-the-o). For example, you can write:

> ```
> Account a = new Account(Name = 'TMP');
> system.debug(Logginglevel.INFO,  'a '+a); // Name = 'TMP'
> Account b = new Account();
> b=a.clone(false,false,false,false); // clone without copying ID and other fields
>
> b.Name = 'TMP NEW';
> system.debug(Logginglevel.INFO,  'a '+a); // Name = 'TMP'
> system.debug(Logginglevel.INFO,  'b '+b); // Name = 'TMP NEW'
> ```

This way, you will have two separate Account objects with different names

Comment: The `Account b = new Account();` accomplishes nothing considering the line right under it. Those two lines can (should?) be combined into one. I.e. `Account b = a.clone();` (the defaults for all the arguments are false for the clone method).